# Is it still possible to use unsecured websockets with Firebase?

Tags: websocket, cocos2d-x, firebase, cocos2d-js

I am trying to integrate Firebase with my Cocos2d-JS application. Unfortunately, Cocos2d-JS does not support secure websockets, so I am trying to connect to Firebase using the WS protocol. Firebase is returning a 404 when I try this. Is it possible to enable the unsecured websocket endpoint with Firebase? It would be great to use this while developing, and then work on getting secure websockets working once the game is finished. The game is just for a uni project, so security is not a major concern.

Comment: This is not possible. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @Kato's comment, this is not currently possible. You must use SSL.

If this is something you need, please make a [Cocos2d-JS feature request](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-js/issues) or a [Firebase feature request](https://www.firebase.com/docs/help/#section-request).